# TypeScript bug? Known type cast to unknown as argument

Tags: typescript

I'm experimenting with some fairly advanced TS to support how we load and parse an xml payload.

This payload can contain several modules (we can specify in the URL which) and for each module picked I want to run a parse function and merge the results in one object.

Here is my [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwIYGcYA0QBsAKSooCmUiUEIcARMmgLQAe2tY+RUlA3AFA8wCeYQnACqAO2ARRAJUIwArlFEAVAYRQAeJQD44AXi5xDcJXEL0YhUQBMUcAN5wA2jjjBRcANaE+EBMYC6AFxwABSMWMFoUG4A5gCUejpuCMQicAC+cAD8acGihABuxNxc-IIi4pIAglAxKoIa2noGRiZmFta2Ds6u7l4+fkpBoVZIMEjByanCCbo6SKJ8Gdm5cPlFUCVlQmISyhAAkqIWBIQAxjB76sI6uqEthsKm5pY2cAtLOSEewTOJcAUIMArHA8oViFwEu1XrYQt9JqIUiQDrMdIDgQkcgdQWtwZteKo4ABZCBWORYQhEpBgPRwba+OAgUnkynU7jbOAAZUIFIuhCsJLJFI0ROeHTe-QZgpZVLAtzgOGAZw86mlFNlABpiVotoSpEgAO4AETGSFVYphnm8UuZ6uptweFT2SkOx2IRAuV121Vq9TU6m5vIsAtt-qJWgj7MJSigCxQCGgIH5JvG5uhnStA2JodlDqMTskLqOJw9l0k10q0lkCmUqg0gfOwbVYYjOp4ZywqFsmCwnPGMBFFozkr8zdz9h4+bAcgARlglXAzpIonILtAQo6p7P52c4FBCEgrJIsEsmUK1MEiY5-BrHQk7OlJ0Zp3OF6g+KJd1gIIeQgpgJEMDRKI8TBDgZAgMARDqFEsQ6HYm5GPu8iKFQ6jhFonBwAA9NhiCyGcAAWf7RHAADUcAAAZZG4HZyFYhC6AAJHYMCEVBAB0tFYPRajpJRcTcPmj6Oi+O5wCwpw9mE2CAcBoFwPqxqmqq8GIYYyE1ogqAYNgeCnFAHGSUQMlYIJjoiVur67kBcYJlAIDNigISjOMwRKSmZrhnEwQxnZibJip4YTvm+ZLqIaB7mo5IwGB+CXEgWCaLGEX2UmVieap8oPkJoWGPZoThZFZ4sgAckgSZwAybGcSVwr3upoVFfAtmpYmABi7h3HVrJgI4PXlUm-i5Xl+YAPIzgAVo2HFdsAMSiCE+4oDFWqtfGHWLa5SBxHEjWPqNUUoe4y0xe8th+W1DmBam4YjRkXAic1jI5tStIIfmEwjKawQONA80APpfbBIEZD59jvHJsTLHMoQOF920cf9MRA2Dt75jOwQuT9EPIwDmNrHIIAzqk6Tgw4BOiETJMkJksMhBTwSI3jM5o4952LsuMAlFwz3Gakdz5AacA9n2YzOY4ADkM6S-45nPeEtL84Z-PSZQ7GUPLXNRStWDwHcyscetaVOaZ5lAA). I've  simplified my code as much as possible without fully abstracting it.

The issue occurs on line 40. There seems to be an issue with `data: RawData<M>`, however, this type is also returned by `parseXml()` and we can see on  line 53 that `new XmlStats(['b']).parseXml("<xml>");` does return type:

```
const xml: {
    orig_b: number;
}
```

So this appears to be working... However, within the method `parseModules()` we get an error:

```
Argument of type 'UnionToIntersection<UnionArgTypes<SelectedModules<M>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ orig_a: string; } & { orig_b: number; }'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ orig_a: string; } & { orig_b: number; }'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ orig_a: string; }'.
      Type 'UnionToIntersection<UnionArgTypes<SelectedModules<M>>>' is not assignable to type '{ orig_a: string; }'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ orig_a: string; }'.(2345)
```

This appears like a bug to me, but I'm not 100% sure given this is some of the most complex TS I've attempted to write.

I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Since your question is just about getting the types right, I think you could remove the parts related to making asynchronous HTTP requests. If your issue is not specific to the `got` module then your [mcve] need not depend on this, either. That said, I think the issue is likely because `M` is a formal type parameter which isn't realised as an actual type where you are using it, so `SelectedModules<M>` and so on cannot be resolved as actual union or intersection types at compile-time. It's hard to say what the solution would be because you didn't describe what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah, without even looking at the code (on mobile) the answer to such things is usually “use type assertions inside the implementation body and move on with your life” because of the compiler’s inability to do much meaningful analysis on complex type expressions involving unspecified type parameters.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm not sure what you mean with I didn't describe what I wanted to achieve... It's in the second sentence of my post...